# Render scald atom with image style, without new scald context?

Tags: media, scald, entities

We have a field or type "Atom Reference", that references scald images.
I want to render these in a node display, using an image style.
For this we need a formatter that will render the scald atom with this image style.

The way we currently do this:

1. Create the image style.
2. Create a scald context, and configure it to use a "transcoder" based on this image style.
3. Use the scald context as a formatter in "manage display" for the node view mode.

This means, we need to create a separate scald context per image style.

What I would prefer is to have just one formatter, and then choose the image style in the formatter settings. Maybe with a "flexible" scald context, and then let the formatter alter this context programmatically.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

The module [Scald style contexts](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald_style_contexts) aims to provide a context for an image style, I think it potentially addresses some of the additional configuration.

Comment: Thank! I guess this would do the trick. Although I already coded a custom module for this purpose now. Still giving a +1 for this :)

Comment: From what I see in the project description, this project will create new transcoders. It does so automatically, but later when you export to features it will still be a bloat of redundant structure.. am I right?

Comment: You gonna have to test for yourself, we are using Breakpoints and Picture, which adds a further layer of config, so this module did not really save us much so we are not actually using it.

Comment: well.. i also have a custom solution for responsive images now :) so same deal. maybe someone else wants to test this. some of this stuff will actually be published soon as contrib module btw :)